# How do I connect a VM to an ad-hoc network?

Tags: networking, adhoc

I need to connect a VM to an ad-hoc network because I have Ubuntu Server running on my VM and I need to access it from other devices on the ad-hoc network. My VM is running on VMware Workstation 15 Player. What could I do to connect the VM to the ad-hoc network hosted on the host computer.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to do that. The first one is to connect your host machine to Ad-Hoc using its driver. The second way is to passthrough Wi-Fi adapter to the VM and connect to Ad-Hoc using driver installed there.

Comment: How do I passthrough my Wi-Fi adapter to the VM?

Comment: If PCI, using VT-d, if it is supported. And any USB Wi-Fi adapter should be supported in any popular VM.

Comment: I have checked the BIOS settings on my computer and VT-d is already turned on. Could you give me a guide on how to use VT-d on VMware Workstation 15 Player? My computer is an Asus gaming laptop.

Comment: https://www.sysadminstories.com/2013/01/vmware-directpath-io-adding-pasthrough.html

Comment: I don't have a VMware Vsphere server, I think it would be better to connect the host machine to ad-hoc, but if I scan the available Wi-Fi networks my ad-hoc network isn't listed. How do I perform the first way, which is to connect my host to the ad-hoc network?

Comment: If you just need network, no Wi-Fi access from a VM, than you can just connect the host to Ad-Hoc, and bridge network adapter to the VM one